# How do I set up internet connectivity from an Ubuntu Server Windows VM?

Tags: networking, server, ssh, internet, virtualization

I was doing this Uni lab in the PCs there with VMWare running an Ubuntu Server 21.10 VM and had to set a static IP to connect to another server via SSH and do other stuff.

However, we were all on the same network and so I had no problems. Now I need to connect to that same server to do the rest of the assignments but I can't get a network connection once I set the static IP.
This is my netplan config:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      dhcp6: false
     addresses:
      - 10.0.16.122/24
     routes:
      - to: default
        via: 192.168.86.1
     nameservers:
       addresses: [1.1.1.1, 1.0.0.1]
```

If I switch the routes back to gateway4 it tells me it's deprecated and won't connect, and if I keep it this way it gives me indentation errors and more.

Also, should I be using my PC's subnet mask or the VM's?
I just need help setting it up so I can get an internet connection. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - unless I'm misunderstanding the case you want to reach that system from home. You said it worked when you "where in the same network" you'll need to achieve the same either by a) VPN into the Uni lab (which will give you an IP in the same subnet and you can reach it) or b) by having the Uni lab expose some ports and forward it to your VM (unlikely to happen as that is considered an entry for attacks).

Comment: Hi @ChristianEhrhardt 
I discussed this issue with my professor today literally an hour before your comment (lol) and he said basically the same thing. He pointed out the dumb mistake that I was doing (which I think is not obvious with the bare ifnfo I provided). I was basically trying to set a static IP with '10.0.16.X', while my LAN started with '192.168'.
So basically I was trying to set a static IP outside my network. It was just a simple mistake from my part!
Thank you for your answer :)